# Computing hash SHA1 in C#

Tags: c#, sha1, password-encryption

In a legacy system we have a password made by the following in SQL Server.

```
select HashBytes('SHA1' , Convert(nvarchar(4000),'MyPassword'))
```

Now, cause a lot of non-functional requirements, we have to compute the same password in C#.

My best try was:

```
public static byte[] CalculateSHA1(string text)
{
    byte[] buffer = UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text);
    SHA1CryptoServiceProvider cryptoTransformSHA1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
    return cryptoTransformSHA1.ComputeHash(buffer);
}
```

But it returns a different array of bytes than the SQL Code returns.

Someone could help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `UTF8Encoding.Default` to `Encoding.Unicode` and the results will match. SQL Server `HashBytes` function uses UTF16 when converting `NCHAR`s and `NVARCHAR`s to bytes before performing the actual hash.